# Codeigniter - How to open specific page depend screen size

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have code in controller Codeigniter:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent:: __construct();
    $this->load->model('berita');
}
public function index()
{
    $data['newsone'] = $this->berita->get_one_top_data();

    if(width.screen > 1000px){ // i need the true code in here
        $this->load->view('home_view_1',$data);
    }
    else{
    $this->load->view('home_view_2',$data); 
    }
}
}
```

how can i open specific page depend on screen size...?

Comment: PHP cannot determine the clients screen size. You have to use JavaScript instead.

Comment: how the code?..